# Why would an angular service api not render to data bindings in the html?

Tags: json, angular, api

I am still new to angular... But, this html renders as a blank page, nothing is shown in the browser. Console.log will log out the data to the console so I know it is visible. This also causes blank rows in a p-table or any other table that you might be using.
What am I doing wrong?

**component.html**

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of myData">{{ item.id }}</div> <!-- should be: 1 2 3 -->
    <div>{{ item[0].id }}</div> <!-- should be: 1 -->
```

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-testing-table',
    templateUrl: './testing-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./testing-table.component.css'],
})
export class TestingTableComponent implements OnInit {
    myData: Posts[] = [];

    constructor(
        private postService: PostService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.postService.get().subscribe((resp) => {
            console.log('got all posts', resp);
            this.myData = resp;
        });
   }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';

import { Posts } from '../models/posts';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PostService {
    public URL = 'https://something.com/typicode/demo/posts';

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {}

    public get(): Observable<Array<Posts>> {
        return this.http.get<Array<Posts>>(`${this.URL}`);
    }
}
```

**model.ts**

```
export class Posts {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}
```

**Response Data from the API get() service.ts**

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Title": "Post 1"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Title": "Post 2"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "Title": "Post 3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a few good days of work with some help from a friend to find out angular is very strict with how it maps the JSON to the Model. The response data has to match 1:1 with the case or it wont work. The error is here:

Make the models match the response:

**model.ts**

```
export class Posts {
    ID: number;
    Title: string;
}
```

OR

Have the api service change what it returns as JSON, and have it return this instead:

**Response Data from the API get() service.ts**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Post 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Post 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Post 3"
    }
]
```